# How do I use elements with sequential but different names into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if the title is accurate. I am still getting familiar with jQuery/JavaScript so please feel free to correct my grammar/terms.

Problem: I have a form page that I need to read and validate the user supplied data when the user clicks send. The data I am having trouble with is contact data. The form by default lists two contacts. There is a button which allows the user to add one new contact at a time dynamically to the page. So, my code might need to validate tens or hundreds of contacts on this page. I cannot change the code/format of the form. I can only add Javascript/jQuery to validate the data.

Each contact is set up within a repeat wrapper like this:

```
<div class="ff-sec-repeat-wrapper">
    <div class="ff-item-row">
        <div class="ff-col-1 ff-label-col">LABELS&STUFF</div>
        <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">
            <input type="textbox"
             id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_1_.FirstName" 
             placeholder=""
             name="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_1_.FirstName" 
             vatt="STRING"
             class="ff-input-type ff-type-text"
             data-maxlengthmessage="Maximum 40 characters" 
             maxlength="40" 
             value=""
             data-requiredmessage="required"
             data-isupsert="false"
             data-ishidden="false" 
             data-vatt="STRING">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ff-item-row">
        <div class="ff-col-1 ff-label-col">LAST_NAME_STUFF_SAME_FORMAT_AS ABOVE</div>
        <div class="ff-col-2 ff-label-col">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ff-item-row">
        <div class="ff-col-1 ff-label-col">EMAIL_STUFF_SAME_FORMAT_AS_ABOVE</div>
        <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">
            <input type="textbox"
            id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_1_.Email"
            placeholder="" 
            name="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_1_.Email"
            vatt="EMAIL" 
            class="ff-input-type ff-type-text" 
            data-maxlengthmessage="Maximum 80 characters" 
            maxlength="80" 
            value="" 
            data-requiredmessage="required" 
            data-isupsert="false" 
            data-ishidden="false" 
            data-vatt="EMAIL">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<div class="ff-sec-repeat-wrapper">
    <div class="ff-item-row">
        <div class="ff-col-1 ff-label-col">LABELS&STUFF</div>
        <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">
            <input type="textbox"
             id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_2_.FirstName" 
             placeholder=""
             name="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_2_.FirstName" 
             vatt="STRING"
             class="ff-input-type ff-type-text"
             data-maxlengthmessage="Maximum 40 characters" 
             maxlength="40" 
             value=""
             data-requiredmessage="required"
             data-isupsert="false"
             data-ishidden="false" 
             data-vatt="STRING">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ff-item-row">
        <div class="ff-col-1 ff-label-col">LAST_NAME_STUFF_SAME_FORMAT_AS ABOVE</div>
        <div class="ff-col-2 ff-label-col">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ff-item-row">
        <div class="ff-col-1 ff-label-col">EMAIL_STUFF_SAME_FORMAT_AS_ABOVE</div>
        <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">
            <input type="textbox"
            id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_2_.Email"
            placeholder="" 
            name="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_2_.Email"
            vatt="EMAIL" 
            class="ff-input-type ff-type-text" 
            data-maxlengthmessage="Maximum 80 characters" 
            maxlength="80" 
            value="" 
            data-requiredmessage="required" 
            data-isupsert="false" 
            data-ishidden="false" 
            data-vatt="EMAIL">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is the basic setup. Each repeat wrapper contains multiple rows with different contact's data. There are many fields for each contact, such as LastName, EmailAddress, ContactRole, etc. But I suspect that once I understand how to access one, the others will essentially be accessed the same way.

*Importantly (I believe):* Each new contact id is sequentially iterated with a Alpha_Number_ combination. So, above, the first contact's FirstName id is `Application__c.Contact.A_1_.FirstName`, while the eigth contact's would be `Application__c.Contact.A_8_.FirstName`. This number changes for all other contact fields like `LastName` and `EmailAddress`.

At a minimum, how can I retrieve all of the contacts' email addresses into an array? This will allow me to do things like check for duplicate email address and match the supplied email addresses to other data I can already retrieve.

Comment: You can certainly achieve this in JavaScript by checking the parent, but it's impossible to know the code to do this, as there are no email addresses in your above example. I'm **assuming** emails come in the format `<div class="ff-item-row">` --> `<div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">` --> `input#Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_1_.Email`? Could you please update your question to show at least two email fields? That would make working out how to target them a *lot* easier.

Comment: Thank you, Obsidian Age. I added more code to show more fields. I believe this shows the structure you asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're trying to figure out how to validate something like the following, without manually writing validation for "contact 1, contact 2, ..., contact 8", etc?

Using `querySelectorAll` will be your friend here. We can use it to grab all of your repeat wrappers and add them to an array, and then you can loop through that array to validate.

Here's a simple example. For demonstration purposes, it will kick out the phony name and add the two valid names to an object. Of course, you'll replace this with your own validation and whatever you do from there. I think effectively what you're looking is a way to loop through an indeterminate amount of fields; which

```
querySelectorAll
```

and a simple loop:

```
for( i = START; i <= NUM_OF_ITEMS; i++ ){
```

Will make simple work of. Check out the following snippet:

```js
// Run this code when #myform is submitted
document.querySelector('#myform').addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page load for demo purposes

  var object = {},
      valid  = 0;

  // Grab an array of all the repeat-wrapper fields
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll('.ff-sec-repeat-wrapper');

  // Loop through that array, it will stop when total # of `repeat-wrappers` has been reached
  for( i = 1; i <= fields.length; i++ ){
    // The "magic" here is the '+ i +', which is replaced with the current iteration number
    // Since i will never be greater than fields.length, it will only run as much as long as needed
    FirstName = document.getElementById('Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_'+ i +'_.FirstName').value;
    LastName  = document.getElementById('Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_'+ i +'_.LastName').value;

  //Example Fields:
  //Email     = document.getElementById('Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_'+ i +'_.Email').value;
  //SomeField = document.getElementById('Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_'+ i +'_.SomeField').value;

    contact = []; // For demo purposes we're making an associative array of valid contacts

    // Put your validation here
    // Demo validation will only kick out the fake name "Foo Bar"
    if( FirstName != 'Foo' ) contact.push( FirstName );
    if( LastName != 'Bar' )  contact.push( LastName );

    // If contact is valid, add it to our object
    if( contact.length > 0 ) object[valid++] = contact;
  }

  console.log( object ); // Will contain 0:John, 1:Jane - having skipped `Foo` for not meeting out validation
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <div class="ff-sec-repeat-wrapper">
      <div class="ff-item-row">
          <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">First
              <input type="text" id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_1_.FirstName" value="John"/>
          </div>
          <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">Last
              <input type="text" id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_1_.LastName" value="Doe" />
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ff-sec-repeat-wrapper">
      <div class="ff-item-row">
          <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">First
              <input type="text" id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_2_.FirstName" value="Foo" />
          </div>
          <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">Last
              <input type="text" id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_2_.LastName" value="Bar" />
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ff-sec-repeat-wrapper">
      <div class="ff-item-row">
          <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">First
              <input type="text" id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_3_.FirstName" value="Jane" />
          </div>
          <div class="ff-col-2 ff-field-col">Last
              <input type="text" id="Membership_Application__c.Contact.A_3_.LastName" value="Smith" />
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was far more than detailed than I even hoped for. With that, I was able to create a nice framework to do some extensive validations.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I could help!